# Touch events in UIViewController instead of UIView

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

I am having trouble getting a UIViewController subclass to handle touch events from one of the sub views.
This is the hierarchy:

```
  UIViewController
        |
  MYGeneric_UIVC
        |
MyAppSpecific_UIVC----- UIView[view_all] 
                           |
                           +-- UIView[view_top] (top section of screen)
                           +-- UIControl subclass[view_middle] (middle section)
                           +-- UIView[view_bottom] (bottom section)
```

The touch events have been working in view_middle (the UIControl subclass) but I realised that in order to modify the UILabel text in view_top and view_bottom to react to what's happening in view_middle, I should instead handle the events in MyAppSpecific_UIVC (as opposed to sending messages around using pointers and delegates which I've seen other people suggest, which seems a bit messy).

---

So I removed the 4 touch event handling methods from view_middle and added them to MyAppSpecific_UIVC. What I think should happen is that if view_middle doesn't handle the events then it should try again going up the hierarchy (view_all, then MyAppSpecific_UIVC).

---

But MyAppSpecific_UIVC never gets any touch events, and I also tried view_all but that didn't work either.

---

Perhaps the nib file links things might be wrong ? 
The file's owner is MyAppSpecific_UIVC. 
The File's owner's 'view' is pointing to 'view_all'.

---

Should the 'Sent Events' of the view_middle (UIControl) be pointing at anything in IB ?

---

Should view_all have User Interaction Enabled, or not (it is off) ?

---

I am loading the nib file from using:

```
nibObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:resource owner:self options:nil];
```

Any suggestions please ?

Comment: add this in viewDidLoad: `self.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;` Does that work?

Comment: no, it is ticked in interface builder already.

Answer (score 0):

change your Uiview class as UIControll it will accept the touch events.

Comment: The UIView gets touch events but I want to change it so the UIViewController gets them...

Comment: I had forgotten that the view where the touches are detected was already a UIControl.

Comment: Yes UIcontroll can get touch event not UIView.

Comment: But surely UIView gets touch events because it extends UIResponder and supports:  touchesBegan:withEvent:, touchesMoved:withEvent:, touchesEnded:withEvent:, touchesCancelled:withEvent:  ??? I'm confused !!